# Where to put imports in an iPython notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a Python programmer, new to IPython notebook.

I have started a notebook that requires me to use the `csv` module in several cells.

It seems that I have to import the module separately for each cell. I can't just put `import csv` at the top of the notebook, I have to write it once in each cell.

Is that correct? It seems very clunky if so, suspect I've missed something obvious!

Comment: No, you don't have to `import csv` in each cell. You can just do it once at the top and csv will be imported for the rest of the session. You do have to rerun that top cell next time you reopen the notebook though, perhaps that's where you're going wrong?

Comment: Warning for IPython notebook newcomers: there are separate commands for "run this cell" and "run all cells". If I change a cell (like adding an import to the first cell, which is where you should put them in my opinion) I usually run all cells starting with that one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you only need to import the module a single time, and it does not need to be in the same cell that you are using it.